# WPF ProgressBar - binding progress value to display on the bar

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I have a progress bar template as below and added a textbloxk to it, to display progress value on top of the bar.
I'm trying to use TemplateBinding to bind value/tooltip of progress bar to the Text of TextBlock and it doesn't work.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
<Grid>
    <Border Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="10" Background="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="10" Background="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2">
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,5,0" Text="{TemplateBinding ProgressBar.Value}"  />
    </Border>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Please let me know, how I can achieve this? or Is there an alternate way?

Comment: It seems like you just want "Value" instead of "ProgressBar.Value". Could you post any System.Data exceptions you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes, your code **is** correct, but `TemplateBinding` uses some sort of black magic when evaluating the expression (there are issues on WP7 vs WP7.1 and Silverlight3 vs. 4). In fact, this kind of binding is just a shorthand form of the traditional binding (see the example below), and, it is better to use the latter to prevent exceptions on various platforms.

Just replace the `TextBlock` binding with this traditional binding:

```
Text='{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}'
```

or, **even better**, this:

```
Text='{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}'
```

Comment: This did the trick for me: `Text='{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}'`